# Unconfirmed bitcoin transaction (Need help)

Tags: transactions, transaction-fees, unconfirmed-transactions, trading, encryption

[image]
I have sent bitcoin since 25th May 2017 till now the transaction haven't confirmed yet.
https://blockchain.info/tx/ac0635c98af0703927f1b364d2d8c19f4b2812c97169c729cb341111adcea866
How can i do? Please kindly help me to get my bitcoin back
Thank you in advance
Tickbit

Answer (score 0):

The transaction you link builds on a chain of approximately 30 unconfirmed transactions. As far as I saw when skimming through, they all pay decent fees with 295sat/B, however due to them being unconfirmed for more than two weeks, probably some have been dropped from the mempool since.

You should make sure that all the transactions are broadcast to the network again, then I think they would confirm easily within an hour or two, as currently transactions at <80sat/B get confirmed.

Comment: How can i do to make it confirm? Please kindly advise me Thank you in advance

Comment: What wallet is it that you're using? Your wallet software should automatically broadcast your transactions again. Otherwise many wallets allow you to export raw transactions which can be manually broadcast on e.g. [blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info/pushtx).